# xsd to class (C#) in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am following a tutorial, in one step it opens "VS2012 arm cross tools command prompt" and executes

```
xsd file.xsd /classes
```

I can't find "VS2012 arm cross tools command prompt" on my computer (my guess it's because I'm using VS2019) so I open the "Developer command prompt for VS 2019" instead, but when I run the command, I get an error:

> "xsd" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file

Can someone tell me how I can create a class from an xsd file in VS 2019? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you searched your C:\ drive for xsd.exe? If you don't find it you will need to install the SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Developer command prompt works for me.  It includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\` in the PATH, and that's where xsd.exe is located (for me...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have installed the Windows [SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). The following could be of help to you...it is .NET Core. Browse to the xsd.exe and add a reference to it in VS 2019.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rgs = new string[]
        {
            @"PathToYourDLL\My.dll",
            "/type:ClassNameToGen"
        };

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) =>
        {
            string error = e.Exception.ToString();

            var typeLoadException = e.Exception as ReflectionTypeLoadException;

            if (typeLoadException != null)
            {
                foreach (var exception in typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions)
                {
                    error += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + exception.ToString();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(error);
        };

        XsdTool.Xsd.Main(rgs);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Simon Wilson, thank you for your answer. Installing the latest .net framework and restart the PC made it work. I am not sure what I should do with the code you posted

Comment: If you have it working then you can ignore my code. this is what I use to create XSD from a type...I think you wanted it the other way right? Sorry, I misread...I'll leave this in case someone wants to do the reverse.

Comment: I am using it from outside an app. Thank you!

Comment: I just re read my first comment and it is wrong: I installed the Windows SDK, restarted the PC and it worked. Thank you for your answer!